# wp_insert_post hook doesn't work when I publish a post from public area. But works fine from admin area. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

When I publish a post on WordPress from ADMIN area, the hook "wp_insert_post" works fine:

```
function testing( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    error_log('testing');
}
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'testing', 10, 3);
```

But when I publish from PUBLIC area (and there are no errors here), even using wp_insert_post to publish the post, the function above isn't called.

Why does it happen? And is it possible to solve that?

Comment: What plug-in you use to let people post from the front-end? Or do you use your own code?

Comment: AccessPress Anonymous Post. Why?

Comment: Do you know a better plugin, Berend?

Comment: I always use gravity forms, but your plug-in also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I downloaded your plug-in and tested it and for me it works just fine. You should know though that WordPress already inserts the post when you request the page, not after you press submit/save. Anyway here is what I posted in the frontend:

[image: frontend]

I added a breakpoint in your function and it gets there just fine:

[image: phpstorm]

So the problem must be elsewhere, are you sure you are checking the error_log in the right place?

Comment: Berend, where exactly did you put my function testing()?

Comment: You should place it in your functions.php from your child-theme, or create a WordPress plugin which I did.

Comment: And where did you put the plugin shortcode? <?php echo do_shortcode('[ap-form]');?>

Comment: I just created a normal page in WordPress from my dashboard and added the text [ap-form].

Comment: The problem happened because I put my function in a plugin file that wasn't visible from frontend. I moved the function to another place and the hook is working now. Thank you so much for your help, Berend =)